# Create Function SQL

Tags: sql

I need to create a function that would split string by element.
'a1,a2,a1,a3' and result should be:

| Value | Counter |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 2 |
| a2 | 1 |
| a3 | 1 |

*This is example of my code (but it needs to work)*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING (
  IN_STRING VARCHAR(1000),
  IN_DELIM VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS TABLE (CNT INT)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  READS SQL DATA
  BEGIN
  DECLARE I INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CNT INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE I < LENGTH(IN_STRING)
  DO
    IF SUBSTR(IN_STRING, I, 1) = IN_DELIM THEN SET CNT = CNT + 1;
    END IF;
    SET I = I + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN CNT;
END;
```

```
select SPLIT_STRING('a1,a2,a1,a3', ',') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?

Comment: Mark Barinstein, DB2 v11.1.4040.491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create such a function in Db2 for LUW.
You may use a built-in functionality.

```
select x.tok as value, count (1) as counter
from 
  -- Here is your table reference
  (values  'a1,a2,a1,a3') mytab (str)
, xmltable
(
  'for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
  passing 
    mytab.str as "s"
  columns 
    tok varchar(4000) path '.'
) x
group by x.tok
```

| VALUE | COUNTER |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 2 |
| a2 | 1 |
| a3 | 1 |

**Update**

The same with a table function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING 
(
  IN_STRING VARCHAR(1000)
, IN_DELIM VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS TABLE (TOKEN VARCHAR (100), CNT INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
RETURN
select x.tok as value, count (1) as counter
from xmltable
(
  'for $id in tokenize($s, $p) return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
  passing 
    IN_STRING as "s"
  , IN_DELIM as "p"
  columns 
    tok varchar (1000) path '.'
) x
group by x.tok
```

```
select *
from table (SPLIT_STRING ('a1,a2,a1,a3', ','))
```

| TOKEN | CNT |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 2 |
| a2 | 1 |
| a3 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lfzr6Ewp)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to create this function.

Comment: A table function is used in the FROM clause, not in the SELECT list. Moreover, your function has a single return column, but your result set has 2 ones. So, do you want a table function with 2 result set columns doin aggregation inside?

Comment: Yeah, I need to table function  set columns doing aggregation inside

Comment: Look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks)), why Db2 is so difficult?)))

Comment: There is nothing complex here at all. You may implement the same with whatever other rdbms (or even with Db2, since it supports sufficient procedural logic for this task, of course) without builtin string tokenizer function, and we may compare the complexity. I believe, that there is no need to use any procedural logic, if a task can be resolved with a single statement.

Comment: @Jhon, you can easily construct a recursive cte that tokenizes the string if you feel that its easier to grasp. Wont be as efficient as any of the suggestions in Marks answer though